# Prove that there is no positive integer n such that n² + n³ = 100.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

There is no positive integer n such that $n² + n³ = 100$
This statement means  :

> For $n^3 + n^2 = 100$, if $n > 0$ then $n \notin \mathbb{Z}$

Assume For $n^3 + n^2 = 100$, if $n > 0$ then $n \in ℤ$

$n^3 = 100 - n^2 = (10-n)(10+n) > 0 $(since if $n > 0$ then $n^3 > 0$)
$\implies n > 10$ or $n < -10$
$n < -10$ cannot be accept because $n > 0$
Therefore we can get only $n > 10$

We can get $n = \sqrt{100-n^3}$
but
$n^3 > 1000$ (since $n > 10$)
$-n^3 < -1000$
$n^2 = 100 - n^3 < -900$
$n^2 < 900$ means $n$ is a complex number
Therefore $n \notin \mathbb{Z}$.
Assumption is false: this is contradiction!
Therefore for $n^3 + n^2 = 100$, if $n > 0$ then $n \notin \mathbb{Z}$ is true.
**Hence there is no positive integer n such that $n^2 + n^3 = 100$**

Is this correct? Are there other solutions to prove it?

Comment: As $5^3>100$ and $4^2+4^3<100$ the problem is solved as $n^2+n^3$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Oh! that's the way. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

$n^3+n^2 = 100 \implies n+1 = (\frac{10}{n})^2$

$\implies n \mid10 $ and $n+1$ is a square number.

There are only $3$ possible values of $n$ from first condition -> $1,2,5$ but none of them give $(n+1)$ as a square number.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is incorrect due to this step:

$$n^3=(10-n)(10+n)>0\implies|n|>10.$$ When $|n|>10$ we have $100-n^2<100-10^2=0$ which is the opposite of what we want.

Thus $-10<n<10$ so $1<n<10$ as $n$ is positive.

---

A much quicker way is to note that $5^3>100$ and $4^2+4^3<100$. Since $n^2+n^3$ is increasing on the positive reals we can immediately see that $n^2+n^3=100$ has no solutions over $\Bbb Z^+$.

Answer (score 0):

$n^2+n^3$ is strictly increasing for $n \in Z^+$

for $n=1,2,3,4$ $n^2+n^3\not=100$

and for $n\geq5$, $n^2+n^3>100$

Answer (score 0):

Modulo $9$, $n^2+n^3\equiv0,2,3,8,6,$ or $5$, but $100\equiv1$.